# Finding the number of sum combinations between two arrays that satisfy a condition

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, math, combinations

**The problem:**

I have 2 arrays *A*[*v*] and *M*[*w*], with length *v* and *w*, respectively. Given two numbers *p* and *q*, I want to find how many combinations of the sum of two elements of these arrays satisfy the following condition:

*p* >= *A*[*v*] + *M*[*w*] <= *q*

**An example:**

Let:

```
A = [9, 14, 5, 8, 12, 2, 16],
v = 7,
M = [6, 2, 9, 3, 10],
w = 5,
p = 21,
q = 24
```

The answer will be 5, because of the following combinations:

1. 14 + 9 = 23
2. 14 + 10 = 24
3. 12 + 9 = 21
4. 12 + 10 = 22
5. 16 + 6 = 22

**What I have tried:**

The following is an implementation of the problem in C++:

```cpp
int K = 0; // K is the answer
for (int i=0; i<v; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<w; j++) {
        if (A[v]+M[w] >= p && A[v]+M[w] <= q) {
            ++K;
        }
    }
}
```

As we can see the above code uses a loop inside a loop, thus making the time complexity of the program *Ο*(*v×w*), pretty slow for large arrays.

**The question**

Is there a fastest way to solve this problem?

Comment: Haven't tested it thoroughly, but sorting and binary search might be applicable.

Comment: What are the `constraints`? What is the `maximum possible size of  the array`? What is the `range of p and q`? What is the `possible size of each element of the array`?

Answer (score 0):

Problem Summary: Given two arrays `A` and `B` with sizes `v` and `w` respectively, find the number of possible pairings of an element from `A` and an element from `B` such that the two elements have a sum that is `>= p` and `<= q`.

The simple, brute force algorithm is essentially what you have currently. The brute force algorithm would simply involve testing all possible pairs, which, as you said, would have a time complexity of `O(v*w)` because there are `v` ways to choose the first element and `w` ways to choose the second element when testing all the pairs.

As @thestruggler pointed out in their comment, sorting and binary search could be applied to create a significantly more efficient algorithm.

Let's say we sort `B` in ascending order. For the test case you provide, we would then have:

```
A = [9, 14, 5, 8, 12, 2, 16]

B = [2, 3, 6, 9, 10]

p = 21 and q = 24
```

Now, notice that for every element in a, we can calculate the *range* of elements in `B` that, when added to the element, would have a sum between `p` and `q`. We can actually find this range in `O(logW)` time by using what is called [Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Specifically, if we were looking to pair the first number in `A` with numbers in `B`, we would binary search for the index of the first element that is `>= 12` and then binary search for the index of the last element that is `<= 15`. The number of elements in `B` that would work in a pairing with the element from `A` is then just equal to 1 plus the difference between the two indexes.

Overall, this algorithm would have a complexity of `O(WlogW + VlogW)` (or `O(VlogV + WlogV)`; if you want to go above and beyond your program could decide to sort the larger array to save time on testing). This is because sorting an array with `N` elements takes `O(NlogN)` time, and because each binary search over a sorted array with `N` elements takes `O(logN)`.

Comment: The complexity would be ```O((V+W)log(VW))```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be solved in following way,
First sort both arrays,
[9, 14, 5, 8, 12, 2, 16] => [2, 5, 8, 9, 12, 14, 16]
[6, 2, 9, 3, 10] => [2, 3, 6, 9, 10]

Now iterate all elements of smaller array and do following,
[`2`, 3, 6, 9, 10],
current element is `2`, subtract it with `p`, lets say it is `num` it means,
`num = p - 2 = 21 - 2 = 19`
Then all numbers in other array, grater than of equals to `19` will make sum `21` with `2`. But no element in other array is grater than or equals to `19` It  means by adding `2` with any element of other array can not grater than or equals to `p`,
Next element which is `3` and it also can not fulfill the requirement, same can be done with other element, so let's directly move to element `9` for explanation,

[2, 3, 6, `9`, 10]
`num = p - 9 = 21 - 9 = 12` and by getting lower bound of `12`, we will get all numbers, those sum with `9` will be grater than or equal to `p`(21), as highlighted below,
[2, 5, 8, 9, `12, 14, 16`],
Sum of these numbers with `9` is grater than or equals to `p`, now it is time to find how may of them will produce sum which is less then or equals to `q`, so to doing that we have to do following,
`num = q - 9 = 24 - 9 = 15` and by finding upper bound of `15` will give all the numbers sum with `9` shall be less than of equals to `q` as highlighted below,
[2, 5, 8, 9, `12, 14`, 16],

This way you can find all combinations having sum, `p >= sum <= q`,

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::size_t combinationCount(int p, int q, std::vector<int> arr1, std::vector<int> arr2){

    std::sort(arr1.begin(), arr1.end());
    std::sort(arr2.begin(), arr2.end());

    std::vector<int>::const_iterator it1 = arr1.cbegin();
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator endIt1 = arr1.cend();

    std::vector<int>::const_iterator it2 = arr2.cbegin();
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator endIt2 = arr2.cend();

    if(arr2.size() < arr1.size()){
        std::swap(it1, it2);
        std::swap(endIt1, endIt2);
    }

    std::size_t count = 0;

    for(; endIt1 != it1; ++it1){

        int num = p - *it1;

        std::vector<int>::const_iterator lowBoundOfPIt = std::lower_bound(it2, endIt2, num);

        if(endIt2 != lowBoundOfPIt){

            num = q - *it1;
            std::vector<int>::const_iterator upBoundOfQIt = std::upper_bound(it2, endIt2, num);

            count += (upBoundOfQIt - lowBoundOfPIt);
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int main(){

    std::cout<< "count = "<< combinationCount(21, 24, {9, 14, 5, 8, 12, 2, 16}, {6, 2, 9, 3, 10})<< '\n';
}
```

Output : `5`